# Output in django django template is rendered as {&#39;__unicode__&#39;: {}}

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-templates

I'm creating an xml using django templating, and it's outputting some of my variables (all of which come from a python dictionary) as `{&#39;__unicode__&#39;: {}` *but not all of them*.

I can't see a pattern in which variables are being broken....

Is there a general reason for this to happen?

---

Here is a rough idea of the code I'm running:

```
from addict import Dict
def get_dictionary(self, orig_dict):
    new_dict = Dict({'default_key':'default_value'})
    if(orig_dict["code"]==0):
        new_dict.other_key = "Double Quoted String"
    elif(orig_dict["code"]==1):
        new_dict.other_key = "Different Double Quoted String"
    return new_dict
```

and eventually when I use it with `render_to_string("xml_template.xml",dictionary=context_dictionary)` into this template:

```
<ParentTag>
    <MyFirstTag>{{new_dict.default_key}}</MyFirstTag>
    <MySecondTag>{{new_dict.other_key}}</MySecondTag>
</ParentTag>
```

And it renders as:

```
<ParentTag>
    <MyFirstTag>default_value</MyFirstTag>
    <MySecondTag>{&#39;__unicode__&#39;: {}</MySecondTag>
</ParentTag>
```

So I don't know if it's [`addict`](https://github.com/mewwts/addict), or something else. Nothing in that package seems to use unicode, and it's 'tested' on python 2.7. This doesn't happen in my python interpreter.

Comment: Show the relevant part of your template, and the code that constructs the dictionary.

Comment: @peterDeGlopper I'll try to edit some in, but I'm heading home atm,  and don't have access to my code.

Comment: Looks like the apostrophe is being encoded.

Comment: @karthkir that's what I'd think if I had any apostrophes.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I'll double check my code at work tomorrow.

Comment: @karthikr It looks like addict is outputting `'':{}` an 'empty dict'. Not sure why it's empty though. If I call `to_dict()` before sending it to django, I just get empty strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is addict's way of sending an empty dictionary. [It's broken](https://github.com/mewwts/addict/issues/54).

It just means you're trying to access a non-existant dictionary value.